# Magento 1.9.1 on option change additional information is not change

Tags: magento, configuration, magento-1.9.1, configurable-product

In **Magento 1.9.1** whenever I will change the `product option (configuration option)` from the dropdown the product price and availability will change but the `additional information` is not changed.

I want if user change the drop-down then the `additional information` of that particular product also change.

[image]

Can any one tell me why it will not change and how to find the solution of my problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity I already posted this on https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177151/magento-1-9-1-on-option-change-additional-information-is-not-change but didn't get any help there?

Comment: You don't appear to be getting much help here either. I'd suggest trying to either improve the question on the Magento exchange site or reading the docs.

Comment: Okay @Enigmativity thanks!  I will try to improve question on Magento exchange